# Scalajs-react: How to invoke a custom method on button click?

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am trying to build a HTML page for my simple application using scalajs-react, and here is my effort:

```
<.div(
        <.p("Welcome to foodland!"),
        <.form(
          <.label("Name of the recipe:",
            <.input.text(^.name := "nameOfTheRecipe")),
          <.br,
          <.label("How to make it:",
            <.textarea(^.name := "steps")),
          <.br,
          <.input.submit(^.value:="Submit")
        )
      )
```

I have put this in my Scala file, and it works fine.

Now I want to invoke a method when user clicks on 'Submit' button, wherein I would like to access the input fields in the form.

How do we do that? I tried with

```
<.input.submit(^.value:="Submit",onClick = handleClick)
```

..where handleClick is defined in the same Scala file as above.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For attributes that are events, in scalajs-react you have to use `Callback`s. Good entry points in the documentation are:

- [VDOM Event Handlers](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/VDOM.md#event-handlers)
- [Callback creation](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/CALLBACK.md#creation)

In your case, it would look like the following:

```scala
  def buildDiv = {
    val div = <.div(
      <.p("Welcome to foodland!"),
      <.form(
        <.label("Name of the recipe:",
          <.input.text(^.name := "nameOfTheRecipe")),
        <.br,
        <.label("How to make it:",
          <.textarea(^.name := "steps")),
        <.br,
        <.input.submit(^.value:="Submit", ^.onClick --> handleClick)
      )
    )
  }

  val handleClick = Callback {
    println("the button was clicked")
  }
```